# Авторизация через Active Directory на Linux

Tags: c#, active-directory

Всем привет.
Вопрос по части AD.
Имеется десктопный софт на Windows.
Нужно применяя авторизациюю через AD, авторизоваться в сервисе, который стоит на сервере с Linux.
Стоит главный вопрос. Возможно ли такое ?
С AD никогда дел не иметл и пока даже не знаю в каком направлении копать информацию.
Если такой подход возможен, подскажите, пожалуйста, в каком направлении искать информацию по этому вопросу.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/290548/3129992

Answer (score 2):

Да, возможно. Для того чтобы пользователи Windows могли авторизоваться на сервере Linux с использованием их учетных записей Active Directory (AD), можно воспользоваться протоколами аутентификации, такими как Kerberos или LDAP.

Один из распространенных способов реализации данной схемы - использование службы "Active Directory Federation Services" (AD FS) для установления доверия между Windows и Linux с использованием SAML (Security Assertion Markup Language) или других протоколов для передачи утверждений о безопасности между системами.

Также возможен подход, когда на Linux-сервере установлены службы аутентификации, способные работать с AD, такие как Samba (для поддержки протокола SMB/CIFS и внедрения службы аутентификации на базе Kerberos) или утилиты, поддерживающие протокол LDAP для работы с каталогом AD.

В любом случае, для реализации данной схемы потребуется настройка и конфигурация как Windows-сервера (AD) так и Linux-сервера, что бы обеспечить безопасную передачу аутентификационной информации между двумя системами.